# iOS emulator no longer running from command line using phonegap

Tags: ios, macos, cordova

My iOS emulator is no longer opening when I run "phonegap run ios" in the terminal on Mac OS X. I receive no error messages and:

[phonegap] Platform "ios" deployed to emulator.

[phonegap] successfully installed onto emulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this is currently a known bug, you can run the emulate command more directly (note you need to build separately):

```
phonegap local build ios
/platforms/ios/cordova/emulate
```

You can also run the application using the same technique:

```
phonegap local build ios
/platforms/ios/cordova/run
```

**NOTE: When using this method to run the app on your phone, the task might get stuck on the splash screen.  To fix this, launch the Activity Monitor on your Mac and quit any processes with the name "ios-deploy".  From there you can launch the application on your phone by clicking the application icon.**

Or, you can even look inside the generated **/platforms/ios** folder and launch XCode project directly to test in an emulator or on your device.  Open project and click the RUN button.

**IMPORTANT:** with all of the above methods, you MUST run the build command before running:

```
phonegap local build ios
```

Comment: Thank you. There was an error opening the iOS Simulator.log with these commands but the actual simulator is up and running!

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but I can say this is a known bug. Here is the bug so you can track it:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5103

Answer (score 1):

I only had this problem after upgrading to 3.1. I downgraded to 3.0 and it works more reliably:

```
npm uninstall -g phonegap
npm install -g phonegap@3.0
```

Also had to delete the platform/ios dir and plugins/ios.json and then run 'phonegap build ios' and 'phonegap run ios'